# Can I use the System.Data.SqlClient provider to establish a connection with an Azure SQL Managed Instance? How about other SQL DBs?

Tags: windows, azure, iis, azure-sql-database, connection-string

Can I use a connection string with the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider to connect to an Azure SQL Managed Instance? Or just to a Microsoft SQL Server?

If so, should I still use the Windows authentication?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes you can use a sql client. I do think managed instance supports sql auth and azure ad auth but not windows auth

Comment: I think you can do it and if so I think windows authentication unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System.Data.SqlClient to connect to Managed Instance.

However, we recommend that you switch to the newer [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) instead.

You can use AD Integrated authentication or [Azure AD Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-service-principal) authentication

#### 3rd party edit

From [dotnet/SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient):

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is a data provider for Microsoft SQL Server
> and Azure SQL Database. Now in General Availability, it is a union of
> the two System.Data.SqlClient components which live independently in
> .NET Framework and .NET Core. Going forward, support for new SQL
> Server features will be implemented in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

If you switch from System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient you have to take care of some [porting todos](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/porting-cheat-sheet.md)

The [FAQ](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) has some additional infos.